# How can I achieve this design using display flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Please see my **HTML and CSS code** below also the image I want to achieve is also below

[image]

```css
.spl-ms-row_recent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.spl-ms_image {
    background-image: url(../media/images/vector_img_recently_img_300x300.png);
    flex-grow: 0;
    width: 16vw;
    height: 16vw;
    max-height: 310px;
    max-width: 310px;
    min-width: 220px;
    min-height: 220px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.spl-ms-row-recent_sub {
    display: flex;
    /* justify-content: center; */
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.spl-msh-wdg3 {
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.spl-msh-wdg3._wdg-tr {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.spl-msh-wdg3._wdg-fr {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="spl-ms-row _recently">
            <div class="spl-ms-row-leg">Menu</div>
            <div class="spl-ms-row_recent">
                <div class="spl-ms-row_image">
                    <div class="spl-ms_image"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="spl-ms-row-recent_sub">
                    <div class="spl-msh-wdg3 _wdg-ft">
                        <div class="spl-ms-code">E0101</div>
                        <div class="spl-ms-mName">Consultant DAE Viewer</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="spl-msh-wdg3 _wdg-sc">
                        <div class="spl-ms-code">E0101</div>
                        <div class="spl-ms-mName">Consultant DAE Viewer</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="spl-msh-wdg3 _wdg-tr">
                        <div class="spl-ms-code">E0101</div>
                        <div class="spl-ms-mName">Consultant DAE Viewer</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="spl-msh-wdg3 _wdg-fr">
                        <div class="spl-ms-code">E0101</div>
                        <div class="spl-ms-mName">Consultant DAE Viewer</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I achieve this design like on the image using CSS Flex

I've also started using display flex however I still can achieve the design that looks a like on the image. Maybe I missing some part on my CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div{
  /*useless*/
  padding: 7px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.parent{
  display: flex;
}
.left{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top-left{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="top-left">
      <div class="top-left-left">top-left-left</div>
      <div class="top-left-right">top-left-right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-left">
      bottom left
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="right">
    <div class="right-box">right-box</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code, now it works. But I think for the Design, it is better to use grid.

```css
.spl-ms-row_recent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.spl-ms_image {
    background-image: url(../media/images/vector_img_recently_img_300x300.png);
    flex-grow: 0;
    width: 16vw;
    height: 16vw;
    max-height: 310px;
    max-width: 310px;
    min-width: 220px;
    min-height: 220px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.spl-ms-row-recent_sub {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.test{
    flex:1;
}

.test-t{
    display:flex;
}

.spl-msh-wdg3 {
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.spl-msh-wdg3._wdg-tr {
    
}

.spl-msh-wdg3._wdg-fr {
    flex: 1;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spl-ms-row _recently">
        <div class="spl-ms-row-leg">Menu</div>
        <div class="spl-ms-row_recent">
            <div class="spl-ms-row_image">
                <div class="spl-ms_image"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="spl-ms-row-recent_sub">
                <div class="test">
                    <div class="test-t">
                        <div class="spl-msh-wdg3 _wdg-ft">
                            <div class="spl-ms-code">E0101</div>
                            <div class="spl-ms-mName">Consultant DAE Viewer</div>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div class="spl-msh-wdg3 _wdg-sc">
                            <div class="spl-ms-code">E0101</div>
                            <div class="spl-ms-mName">Consultant DAE Viewer</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spl-msh-wdg3 _wdg-tr">
                        <div class="spl-ms-code">E0101</div>
                        <div class="spl-ms-mName">Consultant DAE Viewer</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="spl-msh-wdg3 _wdg-fr">
                    <div class="spl-ms-code">E0101</div>
                    <div class="spl-ms-mName">Consultant DAE Viewer</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi Dain Thanks por anwering. Do you have a links on a grid? So I can check on it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Check out Jen Simmons's site, Grid by Example. You'll find an example that can be adapted really easily for this kind of layout, and she's the source on the subject. https://gridbyexample.com/examples/